# ArcGIS Pro map units locked as Degrees - how to change to Meters

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, units

Instructions [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/map-units-location-units-and-display-units.htm) don't seem to add up. I'm not able to change the map units to Meters.

Is there another way?

[image]

Comment: What coordinate reference are you using?

Comment: @Matte: WGS84 lists lat long. I'm trying to use the point density tool and that requires a cell size...which I wanted to define in meters....but because I'm in wgs84, the cell size metric defaults to degrees....which is an odd metric to think about (for me).

Comment: To change the map units, you have to change the coordinate system of the map. As you've already done, you can change the display units.